# Laravel sub join select query

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to work out how to replicate the below query in Laravel. What I'm trying to do is get the very latest status from `table2` / `t2` and merge it with our primary record `table1` / `t1`

```
select id, created_at, t2.status from table1 t1

left join table2 t2 ON 52.id = (
    SELECT MAX(id) from table2
    where table2.submission_id = submission_id
) AND t1.id = t2.submission_id
```

This query above works brilliantly but I can't work out how to replicate this in 'native' Laravel -

```
$query = Table1::query();
$query->join('table2 as t2', function (JoinClause $join) {
    $join->selectRaw('MAX(id)')
        ->where('t2.submission_id', '=', 'submission_id');
}, '=', 't2.id');
```

I've also tried joinSub -

```
$query->joinSub(function (Builder $query) {
                $query
                    ->selectRaw('MAX(id)')
                    ->from('table2 as t2')
                    ->where('t2.submission_id', '=', 'bespoke_submission_id');
            }, 't2', 't1.id', '=', 't2.id', 'left');
```

However I can't seem to get my desired outcome! Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all. My final solution was the following -

```
// write begin making our query
$query = Model::query();

// filter by status
$args = ['status' => 'approved'];

// create our sub query
$subQuery = DB::raw(
    '(SELECT MAX(id) from table2 ' .
    'where t2.submission_id = submission_id)'
);

// join to retrieve our revisions table
$query->leftJoin('table2 as t2', 't2.id', '=', $subQuery);
$query->whereColumn('table1.id', '=', 't2.submission_id');
$query->where('t2.status', '=', $args['status']);

$results = $table->get();
```

This then creates the desired result so thanks @Kyaw Kyaw Soe for the pointer on implementing a bit of `DB::raw()` and @Jonas Staudenmeir for the tip on `$query->whereColumn()`

Answer (score 3):

This code might work,

```
DB::table('table1 t1')
->select(['id', 'created_at', 't2.status'])
->leftJoin('table2 t2', function ($join) {
    $subQuery = DB::table('table2')
                    ->selectRaw('MAX(id)')
                    ->whereRaw('table2.submission_id = submission_id');
    $join->on('t2.id', DB::raw('(' . $subQuery->toSql() . ')'))->whereRaw('t1.id = t2.submission_id');
});
```

Or this one

```
DB::table('table1 t1')
->select(['id', 'created_at', 't2.status'])
->leftJoin('table2 t2', function ($join) {
    $subQuery = DB::raw('(select MAX(id) from table2 where table2.submission_id = submission_id)');
    $join->on('t2.id', $subQuery)->whereRaw('t1.id = t2.submission_id');
});
```

***Note: you can use `->toSql()` method to print out query string before you execute it, to make sure you really get query you want.***

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `whereColumn()` instead of `where()`:

```
->whereColumn('t2.submission_id', '=', 'bespoke_submission_id')
```